# understanding module syntax defined at top of reasonml file

Tags: reason

I am having difficulties finding an answer to the following syntax in reasonml

```
module A = B;
```

This is defined at the top of the `.re` file and I do not know where `B` is coming from.

EDIT:

When I try to log both A and B, with `Js.log` I get an error with the compiler saying a constructor cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

This is a module alias. It binds the name of an existing module referred to by the name `B` to the name `A`.

`B` can refer to any module in scope, and modules can be brought into scope in several ways. A module alias such as this is one way. It could also be a local submodule or a submodule of another module that has been `open`ed. But most modules in scope will typically be toplevel modules, which are created from every source file visible when compiling the current code unit/module. For example, a file named `foo.re` will create a module named `Foo`.

See the [Reason documentation](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/module) and [OCaml documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/moduleexamples.html) on modules for more details.